# Print a number only if no digits are repeated

Tags: c++

I am writing a program which has an output requirement for the number printed to not have a repeated integer in it

i.e. it would not print 122, 161, 998, etc
but it would print any other number such as 123, 345, 742..etc

how do i go about doing this? thanks!

Comment: @hmjd i set each digit to a spot in an array, then in nested for loops i check digit x to i. If the two counters equal each other, then i skip the condition. If x!=i, the program checks to see if check[x]==check[i], if it does, i flag it with a separate counter, and when x and i both reach their maximum i check to see if the number was flagged. If it was flagged, it does not print, otherwise, it prints.

Comment: Please read SO Homework question policy. In particular, 1) always mark homework questions as such, 2) Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first, and 3) Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation. Read more: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C-language compatible solution would be to convert the number to a string and keep a frequency count of the digits and return true if there are duplicates, e.g.:

```c
int has_duplicate_digit(char * s) {
  char digit_count[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  for (int i=0; i<strlen(s); i++) {
    if ('0' <= s[i] && s[i] <= '9') {
      if (++digit_count[s[i]-'0'] > 1) return 1; // true
    }
  }
  return 0; // false
}
```

**[Edit]** You can also save a few bytes (and possibly some time) by using a bitset instead of an int array. For example:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
int has_duplicate_digit2(char * s) {
  uint16_t digit_count = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<strlen(s); i++) {
    if ('0' <= s[i] && s[i] <= '9') {
      uint16_t bit = 1 << (s[i] - '0');
      if (digit_count & bit) return 1; // true
      digit_count |= bit;
    }
  }
  return 0; // false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a 'bit array' to track digits: this is more a 'C-like' way of solve...

```
int number_orig = ...,
    number = number_orig;
    bits = 0;
bool duplicate = false;
while (number != 0 && !duplicate)
{
 int digit = number % 10;
 if (bits & (1 << digit))
   duplicate = true;
 bits |= (1 << digit);
 number /= 10;
}
if (!duplicate)
  cout << number_orig;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `std::set`, loop through the digits, add them to the set, and see if the number of digits is equal to the size of the set. If it is, no numbers are repeated.

If you suspect most numbers fail to meet the requirement, you can check after each insertion whether the digit was actually added to the set or not, and immediately reject the number if it wasn't.

Comment: @user1188823 then I'll repost my solution, which is probably the fastest way to do it but maybe not the most efficient (see also KerrekSB's answer) `std::string str(to_string(integer)); std::set<char> chars(str.begin(), str.end()); if (chars.size() == str.length()) cout << integer;`

Comment: I'd add to that, if the alphabet of the string (or arity of the  number) is small, a pre-allocated array would be a better solution that a set. I.e. for decimal numbers I'd use an array with one entry per alphabetical element (only 10 digits 0 to 9 in our case) to account for these already seen, while for, ehm, *vigintimillial* number--a number in the base 20,000--or a `wchar_t` string, a set would be totally warranted.

Comment: For clarity, this solution would avoid duplicate digits. Ex: 121 would not be allowed since '1' is duplicated. I'm not sure the original poster means by repeating digits. Does it mean consecutive duplicates or just duplicates in general? If the former, std::unique with a vector would do the trick as a quick (to code) way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple string-based solution: Convert, sort, uniquify, count:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

for (unsigned int i = 0; ; ++i)
{
    std::string sorig = std::to_string(i), suniq = sorig;
    std::sort(suniq.begin(), suniq.end());

    if (std::unique(suniq.begin(), suniq.end()) == suniq.end())
    {
        std::cout << sorig << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert number to string (itoa) and it will be easer to solve the core task.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number to a string, and set up 10 bits (all zero) that represent `1 << ( digit - '0' )` you can then check for each digit whether it has been seen before, and if so return. Else set that bit.